# Pip install Airflow fails on Ubuntu 16.04 (with Python 3.5.2)

Tags: apache2, python3

Hi I am trying to install Airflow in my Linux VM (Ubuntu 16.04) inside a Virtual environment.

But when I start Airflow install inside the Python3  Virtual directory, the install fails with the below error:

```
  Running setup.py install for psutil ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command /root/my_airflow/iged-airflow-dags/env/bin/python3 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-86bctfun/psutil/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-52q3vmn3/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /root/my_airflow/iged-airflow-dags/env/include/site/python3.5/psutil:
    ERROR: /usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'python_requires'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/psutil
    copying psutil/_psosx.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/psutil
    copying psutil/_compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/psutil
    copying psutil/_psaix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/psutil
    copying psutil/_psposix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/psutil
    copying psutil/_pslinux.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/psutil
    copying psutil/_pssunos.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/psutil
    copying psutil/_pswindows.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/psutil
    copying psutil/_psbsd.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/psutil
    copying psutil/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/psutil
    copying psutil/_common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/psutil
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_aix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_contracts.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_posix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_osx.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_process.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_linux.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_sunos.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_windows.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_unicode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_system.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_misc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_bsd.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_memory_leaks.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/runner.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/psutil/tests
    running build_ext
    building 'psutil._psutil_linux' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/psutil
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=563 -DPSUTIL_LINUX=1 -I/root/my_airflow/iged-airflow-dags/env/include -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c psutil/_psutil_common.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/psutil/_psutil_common.o
    psutil/_psutil_common.c:9:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "/root/my_airflow/iged-airflow-dags/env/bin/python3 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-86bctfun/psutil/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-52q3vmn3/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /root/my_airflow/iged-airflow-dags/env/include/site/python3.5/psutil" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-86bctfun/psutil/
```

Steps tried so far:

1. Upgrading PIP to latest (19.1.1)
2. Installing setup tools
3. Updating missing pkgs  (following a similar issue solution [Can't install airflow using pip](https://askubuntu.com/questions/944133/cant-install-airflow-using-pip))

But Airflow install is failing inside the Virtual environment.

Any suggestions on how this can be fixed. Thanks in advance

Comment: Installing PythonX - dev packages did the trick.  ```sudo apt-get install python-dev python3-dev ```

Answer (score 1):

Installing PythonX - dev packages did the trick.  `sudo apt-get install python-dev python3-dev` Airflow has been installed.